# Namespace, class and enum javascript intellisense on VS2012

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, enums, namespaces, intellisense

In VS2010 this was possible by adding __namespace = true to an object.
In VS2012 this doesn't seem to work anymore.

How can I restore it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to re-activate enhanced `VS2012 Javascript Intellisense` I have created this project on Github https://github.com/dotnetwise/VS2012-Javascript-Intellisense

Package also on [Nuget](https://nuget.org/packages/VS2012-Javascript-Intellisense/).

This enables more icons to your javascript code members e.g `namespace`, `class`, `enum`, `interface`, fields by their type and even showing which methods come from `function's prototype` and even common shared from `Object.prototype`!